# Avoiding duplicate values in combo boxes

Tags: c#

I have multiple combo boxes in c# I am selecting values in all these combo boxes from the same table and column but the values must be different from each other. how do i can this?

Comment: Implement the `SelectedIndexChanged` event in your comboboxes and filter the items to only show those that are not selected in the other boxes.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask]

Comment: c# ? Are you meaning asp.net, winforms or wpf, or even something else ?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to react to your user selecting an item in one of your comboboxes and filtering the items in the other boxes accordingly. It could look somewhat like this:

```
var comboBoxItems = ... // the data for your comboboxes
var validItems = comboBoxItems;

public void cbSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItem = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem;
    validItems = validItems.Where(i => i != selectedItem);

    // set validItems as data source for your other comboboxes
}
```

Of course you'll have to add better handling of which items to keep in `validItems`, this is just a simplified example.